# Form Decision - JavaScript / AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a little dilemma with the decision part of my form.  I'm attempting to create a form with radio buttons and a checkbox in an html page but I would like to retrieve data from my .php page. 
I think there's an issue with the .php portion of the code. I'm getting a response from each 'if' statement regardless of the selections I make. 
for Example - If I select radio1 & checkbox I get "Radio One AND checkbox.Radio Two AND checkbox.Radio Three AND checkbox." This is the type of result with any query.

Suggestions ?

HTML FORM

```html
    // start the query string
    var QueryString = "form_test.php?";
    
      if (document.getElementById("radio1").checked == true  && document.getElementById("box").checked) {
      
      QueryString = QueryString + "radio1=" + document.getElementById("radio1").value + "box=" + document.getElementById("box").value;

     } else if (document.getElementById("radio2").checked == true  && document.getElementById("box").checked)  {
      
      QueryString = QueryString + "radio2=" + document.getElementById("radio2").value + "box=" + document.getElementById("box").value;

     } else if (document.getElementById("radio3").checked == true  && document.getElementById("box").checked)  {
      
      QueryString = QueryString + "radio3=" + document.getElementById("radio3").value + "box=" + document.getElementById("box").value;
     } 

  //alert(QueryString);
  xmlHttp.open("GET", QueryString, true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  }

</script></head>

<body>
<p>Test Form</p>
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="POST">
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="radbutton" id="radio1">
    <label>Radio One</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="radbutton" id="radio2">
    <label>Radio Two</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="radbutton" id="radio3">
    <label>Radio Three</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="box">
    <label>CheckBox</label>
  </p>
   <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Test Form" onclick="ajaxFunction();"/>
  </p>
</form>
  <p>
    <div id="OutputPane">
    </div>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP CODE

```html
<?php

if ((isset($_GET['radio1']) || isset($_GET['box']))) {
    echo "Radio One AND checkbox.";
} else {
 echo "Radio One";
} 

if ((isset($_GET['radio2']) || isset($_GET['box']))) {
    echo "Radio Two AND checkbox.";
} else {
 echo "Radio Two.";
}


if (isset($_GET['radio3']) || (isset($_GET['box']))) {
    echo "Radio Three AND checkbox.";
} else {
 echo "Radio Three.";
}


?>
```

Comment: If your `$_GET['box']` checked no matter of radio-button every case will return true, because `true || false` is `true OR false` return true

Comment: That makes sense but I'm not sure how to correct it

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your code, such as:

- There's no `value` attribute in your radio buttons, so you won't get anything with `document.getElementById("radioX").value`. Add a `value` attribute in your radio buttons,

  ```
  <input type="radio" name="radbutton" id="radioX" value="radioX" />
  ```
- Missing `&` between `radioX=...box=...`. It should be like this,

  ```
  ... document.getElementById("radioX").value + "&box=" + ...
  ```
- Change your `QueryString` in the following way,

  ```
  QueryString = QueryString + "radio=" + ...
  ```

  Because in the way it'd be easier for you to access `$_GET['radio']` values in the backend PHP page.
- Change `<div id="OutputPane">` to `<div id="DisplayBox"></div>`.

So your code should be like this:

**HTML**

```
<p>Test Form</p>
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="POST">
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="radbutton" id="radio1" value="radio1" />
        <label>Radio One</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="radbutton" id="radio2"  value="radio2" />
        <label>Radio Two</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="radbutton" id="radio3" value="radio3">
        <label>Radio Three</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="box">
        <label>CheckBox</label>
    </p>
        <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Test Form" onclick="ajaxFunction();"/>
    </p>
</form>
<p>
    <div id="DisplayBox"></div>
</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
// start the query string
var QueryString = "form_test.php?";
if (document.getElementById("radio1").checked == true){
    QueryString += "radio=" + document.getElementById("radio1").value;
} else if (document.getElementById("radio2").checked == true){
    QueryString += "radio=" + document.getElementById("radio2").value;
} else if (document.getElementById("radio3").checked == true){  
    QueryString += "radio=" + document.getElementById("radio3").value;
} 
if(document.getElementById("box").checked){
    QueryString += "&box=" + document.getElementById("box").value;
}
```

**PHP**

```
$str = '';
if(isset($_GET['radio'])){
    switch($_GET['radio']){
        case 'radio1':
            $str .= 'Radio One';
            break;
        case 'radio2':
            $str .= 'Radio Two';
            break;
        case 'radio3':
            $str .= 'Radio Three';
            break;
    }
}
if(isset($_GET['box'])){
    $str .= !empty($str) ? ' AND ' : '';
    $str .= 'Checkbox';
}
echo $str;
```

Comment: I had many more mistakes than I thought !! I'm showing no result when only the radio button is selected

Comment: @Whistler It's working correctly on my end. Paste your code on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/index.php) and give me it's link here.

Comment: My mistake AGAIN ! I missed a line of code. THANKYOU !

Answer (score 0):

Is it php-behavior you need?

```
if (isset($_GET['box'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['radio1'])) {
        echo "Radio One AND checkbox.";
    }

    if (isset($_GET['radio2'])) {
        echo "Radio One AND checkbox.";
    }

    if (isset($_GET['box'])) {
        echo "Radio Three AND checkbox.";
    }
} else {

    if (isset($_GET['radio1'])) {
        echo "Radio One";
    }

    if (isset($_GET['radio2'])) {
        echo "Radio Two";
    }

    if (isset($_GET['radio3'])) {
        echo "Radio Three";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's closer but doesn't work out quite right. with the radio button selected and not the checkbox, no echo is displayed.     If both are selected then "radio One" or "radio Two" ETC .. is displayed, it doesn't echo the correct statement. (if at all.)

Comment: Just change the order. I will improve my answer too

Comment: It's very possible the problem could be with my IF and QUERY statements in the html form.

Comment: You have no case when checkbox selected separatelyor radio-button only. The same logic as php-example I gave you.